# How can you allocate a role to a websphere user via JMX?

Tags: authorization, websphere, jmx

I've managed to create a a new user from a servlet using VMM.  The problem I now have is in allocating a role to the user.  Does anyone know how I could make give the new user a websphere monitor role from within the servlet ?

cheers,

Trevor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you can't through the VMM service which is what I was really looking for.  The best idea is to have groups to each role mapped in advance.  Then you can use VMM to add users to the existing groups as required.